# How to show the Kloosterman sum to be non zero?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $m,n,c\in\mathbb{N}$ $$S(m,n,c)=\sum_{(x,c)=1, x\in \{1,...,c\}} e^{\frac{2\pi(mx+n\overline{x})}{c}}$$
where $x\overline{x}\equiv 1 $(mod) $c$.

I am working on a problem where I wish to show Kloosterman Sum $S(1,a,p)\neq 0$ where $p$ is a prime number. I came across an answer. However I am not able to understand it properly. Any help is much appreciated. Here is a link to the answer.

https://mathoverflow.net/a/188454/123716

I specifically want to show (2.1) of the answer.

Comment: Note that $e^{2ki\pi/p}, 0<k<p$ are a linear basis of the cyclotomic field over the rationals, so any linear combination of such with rational coefficients is not zero unless all the coefficients are zero; in particular any sum with $p-1$ terms or less of $e^{2ki\pi/p}$ and rational coefficients is non zero unless the coefficients are zero (if one term is $1$ at least one another with $k\ne 0$ is missing, so it has non zero coefficient when you write $1$ as minus the sum of all)

Comment: Got it.. Thank you sir..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $S(1,a,p)=\sum_{y=1}^{p-1}e^{\frac{2i\pi}{p}(y+y^*)}$ then it is non-zero in $\Bbb{Z}[e^{2i\pi /p}]\cong \Bbb{Z}[x]/(\Phi_p(x))$ because there is a ring homomorphism $$\Bbb{Z}[e^{2i\pi /p}]\to \Bbb{Z}[x]/(\Phi_p(x))\to 
\Bbb{Z}[x]/(\Phi_p(x),p)$$ $$=\Bbb{Z}[x]/((x-1)^{p-1},p)\to\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x-1,p)\to \Bbb{F}_p$$ sending $e^{2i\pi/p}$ to $1$ and $S(1,a,p)$ to $-1$.

Comment: Thank you so much...However how do we get the sum to be nonzero....

Comment: @JishuDas A ring homomorphism cannot send $0$ to a nonzero element.

Comment: Okay got it..since supposing S(1,a,p)=0 then its image will be zero..(which is -1 in this case)..Thank you again..